No entiendo como tratar este test
No entiendo ya, no entiendo nada. Quiero hacer que cuando gestiono la longitud del texto sea al presionar el boton "submit". Para esto gestiono el validateLength para que si es menor a 3 caracteres me de un error. Pero el problema es que me tira el test que JAMAS LLEGA EL ERROR, es decir, por la asincronica "el error no carga en el momento". Pero si esta, esta ahi! No entiendo como tratar esto ya, me estoy mareando y ya intente de todo.
No me esta tomando el error cada que llamo al "validateLength" por la asincronica, al menos eso supongo yo, pero claro, ya use promesas, async await y etc... y nada, sigue igual. Si lo pongo como otra condicion del useEffect me agarra bien, pero claro, justamente para este caso quiero evitar tener que preguntar por cada caracter ingresado su longitud, si no mas bien cuando ya se ingresa el titulo por completo
Solucionado: Solamente use una funcion auxiliar como refreshError para actualizar el error y evitar esa asincronia que hace que mi error no se ejecute correctamente:


function useTaskTitle(){
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  let isFirstInput = useRef(true);

  const refreshTitle = (newTitle) => {
    setTitle(newTitle);
  }

  const refreshError = (newError) => {
    setError(newError);
  }

  const validateLength = (newTitle) => {
    if(newTitle.length <= 3){
      refreshError('El titulo tiene menos de 3 caracteres!');
      return
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isFirstInput.current){
      isFirstInput.current = !(title === ''); //Cambiar luego sacando el !.
      return
    }

    if(title.startsWith(' ')){
      refreshError('El titulo no puede empezar con un espacio vacio');
      return
    }

    const isNumber = title.split('').some(char => '0123456789'.includes(char));
    if(isNumber){
      refreshError('El titulo no puede contener numeros');
      return
    }
  }, [title]);

  return { title, refreshTitle, error, validateLength};
}

function TaskForm({ getNewTask }){
  const { title, refreshTitle, error, validateLength} = useTaskTitle();

  const handleValue = (event) => {
    refreshTitle(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(error) return
    validateLength(title);
    getNewTask(title);
    refreshTitle('');
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type='text' onChange={handleValue} value={title} name='input-add-taskTitle' placeholder="Ingresa el titulo de la tarea"/>
        <button>Agregar</button>
      </form>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
    </header>
  )
}


Bueno aquí title.length <= 3 se esta evaluando que la longitud sea menor o igual a 3...y tu estas buscando que si es menor a 3 caracteres me de un error.

Si, el problema viene cuando uso el setError en const validateLength, la asincronia no me esta permitiendo actualizar correctamente el error como deberia. Al menos esto es lo que veo, pero no veo como asignarloooo, estuve dandole con promesas, async await de 30 mil maneras y ni una me lo devuelve correctamente antes de ejecutar el resto del codigo del handleSubmit. Es decir, ya me carga todo y el error a ultimo momento

JS se ejecuta muchísimo más rápido de lo que cualquier usuario puede teclear, si quieres comprobar que un mensaje aparece en pantalla tras teclear algo... dale tiempo! Usando waitUntil puedes esperar a que el campo del texto aparezca, y LUEGO es cuando compruebas su contenido

Ya, pero el problema no es cuando tecleo en el momento, si no cuando yo apreto el boton de "submit" del formulario, necesito verificar que el texto entero sea mayor a 3 caracteres digamos. Pero claro, al ser asincrono entonces no puedo verificarlo correctamente antes de ejecutar las siguientes instrucciones.
Voy a probar lo del waitUntil (creo lo habia usado igual) pero tengo mis dudas aun. Aun asi, eso que me pasas estaria bien dentro del test, pero a la hora de llevarlo a codigo de produccion no tengo un waitUntil ahi. Es decir, que aplico, un setInterval?

Al final probe  el waitUntil, hasta puse un setTimeout y nada, simplemente me da error.

Ya lo solucione, al final solo hice el setError en una funcion aparte como un refreshError donde le paso como parametro el error, asi rompi su asincronia y me funciona. Gracias de todas formas!
